# How do I replace text with a linebreak using regular expressions

Tags: regex, editpad

I have written a program that searches for 'opens' without matching 'closes' in a target file.   It produces an output like this:

```
open
close
open
open
close
```

In this example here the second 'open' is not immediately followed by a matching 'close', so I consider that an error.   My text-editor (editpad) has a regular-expression search/replace feature, which I would like to use to get rid of all correct pairs, so I can notice easily the incorrect situations.   I tried replacing the following

```
open\r\nclose
```

I thought that this would match the two words and the line-break between them (I'm using Windows).  This did not work.

Does anyone have an idea why it didn't?

Comment: Are there any trailing spaces between them? Have you tried using regex to just search for \r\n to see if it picks it up what's between them at all?

Comment: Did you select the `Regex` mode? Click `Regex` and then hit `Replace all`

Comment: BTW, is the expected result just a single `open` left in the document?

Comment: does it work when you change it to this? open[\r\n]close

Comment: It can't work if OP does not select a regex search and replace mode and line endings are CRLF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the `Regex` mode, your regex will work, but I also suggest making `\r` optional by appending `?` after it to support LF endings, too:

```
open\r?\nclose
```

See the screenshot with settings and proof it works in *EditPad*:

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting whether `open\Rclose` works, as that would capture all kind of line endings.

Comment: @JoopEggen That was the first thing I tried and it did not work. The `\R` is highlighted red signalling wrong syntax.